# How can I center my ggplot map of the world on the Atlantic ocean instead of the pacific?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As the title states, I'd like to center my map on the Atlantic Ocean instead of the pacific and I don't want Africa to be cut off.

Here is my plot code so far.

```
ggplot(world_map2019, aes(x = long, y = lat, group= group, fill = Total)) +
geom_polygon(color = "black") +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
coord_fixed(1.3) +
theme_void()
```

Here's my plot:

[image]

Here's what world_map2019 data looks like:

[image]